# How to show any space is dually scattered?

Tags: general-topology

As the title explains, how to show any space is dually scattered?

> A topological space $X$ is *dually scattered* if for any neighbourhood assignment $\{ O_x : x \in X \}$ there is a scattered subspace $Y \subseteq X$ such that $\bigcup_{x \in Y} O_x = X$.)

Thanks ahead:)

Comment: You should probably include the definition of the quite uncommon notion of _dually scattered_ to your question.

Comment: I've noticed that you have asked a lot of questions recently. I wanted to make sure that you are aware of the quotas 50 questions/30 days and 6 questions/24 hours, so that you can plan posting your questions accordingly. (If you try to post more questions, stackexchange software will not allow you to do so.) For more details see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/4770/). I am not saying that there is anything wrong about asking questions - I just wanted you to know this, so that you don't get to a situation when you can't ask questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\{ O (x) : x \in X \}$ be any neighbourhood assignment of the space $X$.  For as long as possible inductively construct a (transfinite) sequence $\{ x_\alpha : \alpha < \eta \}$ in $X$ so that

- $x_\alpha \notin \bigcup_{\xi < \alpha} O (x_\xi)$.

(If $\{ O ( x_\xi ) : \xi < \alpha \}$ does not cover $X$ take any $x_\alpha \in X \setminus \bigcup_{\xi < \alpha} O ( x_\xi )$.)

Letting $Y = \{ x_\alpha : \alpha < \eta \}$, note that by construction we will have that $\bigcup_{\alpha < \eta} O ( x_\alpha ) = X$, so it suffices to show that $Y$ is scattered.  But note that if $A \subseteq \eta$ is nonempty and $\alpha_0 = \min (A)$ then $x_{\alpha_0}$, is an isolated point of $\{ x_\alpha : \alpha \in A \}$.  (By construction we have that $O( x_{\alpha}) \cap Y \subseteq \{ x_\xi : \xi \leq \alpha \}$.)

Comment: How to see $x_{\alpha_0}$ is an isolated point? do we need to prove that $x_{\alpha_0}$ is open in $Y$?

Comment: @Paul: You only need to show that $\{ x_{\alpha_0} \}$ is open in the subspace $\{ x_\alpha : \alpha \in A \}$.  The parenthetical remark at the very end should lead you in the right direction.

Comment: $Y$ is scattered iff every non-empty subset $A$of $Y$ contains at least one point which is isolated in $A$. Right?

Comment: @Paul: Yes, absolutely correct.